# What are the my options for apps to share local files over the internet

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-sharing, file-transfer

It's about +200GB so don't recommend Dropbox, SkyDrive or something similar.

The computer hosting the files is behind a NAT'ed home router.

The files are currently shared with ftp but I want to know if there are any other options since using a ftp-client with SSL and non standard ports is apparently "to tricky".

Authentication is a must, ease of use fairly important, speed not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you've read [What's the Easiest Way to Share Large Files and Media with Friends?](http://lifehacker.com/5472050/whats-the-easiest-way-to-share-large-files-and-media-with-friends), but just in case you haven't.

The top recommendation there was [Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/overview/) with the [File Sharing app](http://unite.opera.com/application/132/)

Answer (score 3):

If it is just one way sharing, setup something like WAMP Server, and simply serve the files via a web server.  However the drawback is you loose the benefit of things like 'file resume' which you get through FTP, authentication can be enabled here.

You could always create torrents of each file / sharable item, and setup your own tracker, and supply only that user with the torrent.  You would run a local torrent client that would seed all your files.

Depending on the tracker you setup, you would have authentication etc;

This is a very open ended question, really depends on what you feel (or your user) comfortable with.

Comment: +1 for a web server. If the sharing is one direction, this would be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Hamachi²](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) by LogMeIn and create a VPN between the two computers. then just transfer the files as you would across a local network.

Comment: ...also known as a VPN.

Comment: that was the acronym i wanted, thanks. answer edited.

Answer (score -1):

If youd be on linux id say RSYNC but since its tagged with windows i would do [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)

This enables you to do incremental changes as well

Comment: Don't want syncing, want sharing.